# Sort multi-dimensional array by child key date?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => The Name
            [description] => description
            [date] => Thur, May 5 @ 7:00 p.m.
            [rating] => PG
            [year] => 2011
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 2
            [description] => description 2
            [date] => Sun, May 8 @ 7:30 p.m.
            [rating] => 14A
            [year] => 2011
        )
```

There are about 5-10 more parts.

What I'm ultimately wanting to do is to use the date part of the array to group these items by day (I.e., "all items with "date" falling into "May 8" should be grouped as such).

Any idea how I'd go about this? Note that the "date" field is stored as such in DB -- that's not a timestamp converted from date(); or whatever.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your own sort function and call it using [usort](http://php.net/usort).

For example (not considering the intricacies of your timestamp format):

```
function date_sort($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['date'], $b['date']); //only doing string comparison
}

usort($array, 'date_sort');
```

To complete date_sort, you'll somehow need to convert the dates to comparable types. Here's a solution which converts them to UNIX timestamps:

```
function convert_date($time) {
  $time = substr($time, strpos($time, ',')+1);
  $time = str_replace('@', ',', $time);
  $time = str_replace('.', '', $time);
  return strtotime($time);
}

function date_sort($a, $b) {
  $a = convert_date($a['date']);
  $b = convert_date($b['date']);

  if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: This totally worked; thanks a ton! That said -- I'm running into a problem still. In the example above, I just have a number for the array key (I.e., first element), but in reality, the array key is the post's slug (I.e., a random string). After running usort, the array key is converted to a number. Any way around that?

Comment: Nevermind! uasort(); in place of usort(); does the trick. Thanks, and apologies for the delay in accepting this as my answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use @Emil Vikström solution, with strtotime as comparing function

function date_sort($a, $b) {

$a = strtotime($a['date']);
$b = strtotime($b['date']);

return ($a == $b) ? 0 : ($a>$b ? - 1 : 1);

}

usort($array, 'date_sort');

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php should deal with most textual dates written in english.

Comment: strtotime doesn't handle this format, but I've updated my answer with a function which converts the original format to something strtotime can understand.

Answer (score 0):

For grouping your data by date, run this little loop

```
$sortedArray = array();
foreach($dataListing as $data){
     //parse your $date field with an reg exp and transform it into integer with format MMDD
     $sortedArray[$dateIntegerFormated][] = $data;
}
ksort($sortedArray);
$sortedArray = array_values($sortedArray);
```

And you can use usort for sorting by time into each group

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$arrArray  has array you have specified;

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($arrArray as $key => $value){

    $date1 = substr($value['date'], 0, strpos($value['date'],'@')-1);
    $newArray[$date1][] = $value;


}
print_r($newArray);
```